# DynamoDB ExclusiveStartKey error The provided starting key is invalid

Tags: dynamodb-queries, aws-sdk-js, amazon-dynamodb

Well hello fellas, i'm starting in dynamodb and i have some missunders when i want to use the ExclusiveStartKey.currently im working with the GSI and heres is how i have the params for the query

```
{
   TableName: 'Search',
   IndexName: 'GSI1',
   ExclusiveStartKey: {
     GSI1PK: { S: '8a2bb021182ffff' },
     GSI1SK: { S: '5#182854f0-c4ea-39c7-a3f5-4b0b0d947cea' }
   },
   KeyConditionExpression: 'GSI1PK = :gsiHk AND begins_with(GSI1SK, :entityType)',
   ExpressionAttributeValues: { ':gsiHk': { S: '8a2bb021182ffff' }, ':entityType': {S:'5'}},
  Limit: 500
 }
```

and this returns me an error

```
ValidationException: The provided starting key is invalid
```

Is this the correct way to use it or how can i fix it ??

Comment: Can you execute the query without `ExclusiveStartKey`?

Comment: You'll need to include the table's partition key and sort key (if defined) into the `ExclusiveStartKey`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's uncommon to explicitly set an `ExclusiveStartKey`

From the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html#DDB-Query-request-ExclusiveStartKey):

> ExclusiveStartKey The primary key of the first item that this
> operation will evaluate. Use the value that was returned for
> LastEvaluatedKey in the previous operation.

so the normal use of Query, given it's 1MB read limit is in a loop as shown in the following pseudo-code

```
do 
  result=Query(parms);
  //process results
  parms.ExclusiveStartKey = results.LastEvaluatedKey;
until results.LastEvaluatedKey is null;
```

I supposed there's no reason you couldn't explicitly set it, but I don't see that the format is documented anywhere.  You'll have to examine what's returned in `LastEvaluatedKey`

Comment: thanks, that solve my problem i was setting explicitly the ExclusiveStartKey using just 2 params of the LastEvaluatedKey. I didnt know you need to use the complete object